# HTML File that watches folder and displays images

Tags: html, web

Can you have a HTML file "index.html" sitting in a folder that looks at an images folder and will render whatever is in that folder with certain styling?

The catch is the images folder can be added to so can it watch all new files added and render them.

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1):

HTML Documents when served to the client, are rendered in the browser, which, even with JavaScript, will not know the layout of the filesystem on the server for your images folder.

The only really logical way to do this is use a server side language to processess the request (eg: PHP) to list all the files and write the HTML needed dynamically.

The alternative would be to have some sort of endpoint that would list the image names, and use javascript to dynamically add them to the document on page load, at the end of the day it's personal preference, but without either enabling directory listings for your webserver or using a server sided language of somesort somewhere, what you're asking isn't really possible.

Comment: For example, maybe you don't have the page be php for the image list, but have a php script somewhere else that is requested via AJAX to get a list of images

Comment: I see, so could have an AJAX function in my HTML that calls a Javascript function that gets a list of images. Then render those on the page?

Comment: That's not _exactly_ how it works, it's moreso like this, your browser loads the page, then loads the javascript, your javascript would, via ajax, send a secondary request to another page, which would need to be dynamic (so probably php or something) that outputs a list of images, that gets returned to the javascript, which then should add the images to the document

Comment: So my javascript sends a command via AJAX to a secondary webpage (.PHP file) that looks at the current directory gets a list and sends them back to the first webpage. How would the list be parsed back into the HTML?

Comment: You'd send the list as something like JSON, then create the image elements and append them to the DOM